# how do I check if each value of an array is between a range if the array is a non primitive type

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, I want to check each value of dice.

If the value is ranges between 1 and 6, inclusive, then I want to such value into the array count.

The problem is that dice is an object, not a primitive, which I declared earlier thus the `>=` operator does not work.

```java
    public int[] getValueCount() {
        int[] count;
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; ++i) {
        if ((dice[i] >= 0) && (dice[i] <= 6)) {
                count[i] = dice[i];
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Use an Interface, which offers a contract to make that check in your objects.

Comment: Presumably your object has some field or method that gives you the number...

Comment: You can create a span and use span.contains(...) https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/util/Span.java

Answer (score 1):

I regret to inform you that Java doesn't support operator overloading like other languages such as C++. It was a decision made by the designers with the hope that would make the language simpler to use.

However, there are other options available that you could implement.

The one option that could work very well for you, could be implementing the the Comparable interface.

```java
import java.lang.Comparable;

public class Dice implements Comparable<Dice> {

    /* Code */

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Dice otherDice) {
        return this.value - otherDice.value;
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

The good thing is that you can apply many things with it such as using the Comparator interface:

```java
Comparator<Dice> compareByValue = Comparator.comparing(Dice::getValue);
```

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own comparison method inside Dice class '.greaterOrEqual(x)' or access the data on Dice class directly and compare that value instead

Comment: how would you compare the data directly